# Unable to append data to an existing csv file in AWS S3 using python

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a csv file in my s3 bucket and configured aws cli in my local machine. I want to append the data to that csv file whenever I call my python script, but i am not able to do that.

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
bytes_to_write = df.to_csv(None, header=None, index=False).encode()
file_name = 'test.csv'
# get the existing file
current_data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='test-bucket', Key=file_name)
# append
appended_data = current_data + bytes_to_write
# overwrite
s3_client.put_object(Body=appended_data, Bucket='test-bucket', Key=file_name)
enter code here
```

I have tried the above code but unfortunate couldn't complete the action, i got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
    appended_data = current_data + bytes_to_write
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'bytes'
```

Any solution for this? please help me!

Comment: What I can understand from this error log is that you don't have your current_data and bytes_to_write in the same format. You need to convert you current_data to data frames and then trying to upload it.

Comment: how can i convert to a data frame, I have tried this "df2 =pd.DataFrame(current_data)"
but still having the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
current_data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='test-bucket', Key=file_name)
```

As described [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object), get_object return a dict

You are probably looking for

```
s3_client.get_object(Bucket='test-bucket', Key=file_name)['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response
I have  changed the line  "current_data = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='test-lambda-shyam', Key=file_name)['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")". but I got an error like this "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 19, in <module>
    appended_data = current_data + bytes_to_write
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str"

Comment: `.decode("utf-8")` is transforming bytes to str - just remove it